# How to use GridSearchCV on LSTM model?

Tags: python, time-series, regression, lstm, gridsearchcv

I am not sure how to use GridSearchCV in order to optimize the LSTM model. I went through this tutorial "https://machinelearningmastery.com/grid-search-hyperparameters-deep-learning-models-python-keras/"; however, they did things separately. I am also not sure how they were able to get results since it does not seem like they compared test and train in the tutorial. The model is working attached image), but I'm trying to make it better. Where it says "Grid Search" in my code is where I get lost on how to proceed. Any help or tip is welcomed.

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the training set
dataset_train = pd.read_csv('IBM_Train.csv')
training_set = dataset_train.iloc[:, 1:2].values

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1))
training_set_scaled = sc.fit_transform(training_set)

# Creating a data structure with 60 timesteps and 1 output
X_train = []
y_train = []
for i in range(60, 1228):
    X_train.append(training_set_scaled[i-60:i, 0])
    y_train.append(training_set_scaled[i, 0])
X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)

# Reshaping
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))

# Part 2 - Building the RNN

# Importing the Keras libraries and packages
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor

# Initialising the RNN
def lstm_model():
    regressor = Sequential()
    regressor.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1)))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
    regressor.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
    regressor.add(LSTM(units=50))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
    regressor.add(Dense(units=1))
    regressor.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
    return regressor

regressor = KerasRegressor(build_fn=lstm_model, epochs=100, batch_size=16, verbose=0)

regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Grid Search
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
units = [30, 50, 70, 90]
dropout_rate = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
activation = ['relu', 'tanh', 'sigmoid', 'hard_sigmoid']
batch_size = [8, 16, 32, 48]
epochs = [50, 100, 150, 200, 250]
optimizer = ['Adagrad', 'Adadelta', 'Adam', 'Adamax', 'Nadam']
param_grid = dict(units=units, dropout_rate=dropout_rate, activation=activation,
                  batch_size=batch_size, optimizer=optimizer, epochs=epochs)


# Part 3 - Making the predictions and visualising the results

# Getting the real stock price of 2017
dataset_test = pd.read_csv('IBM_Test.csv')
real_stock_price = dataset_test.iloc[:, 1:2].values

# Getting the predicted stock price of 2019
dataset_total = pd.concat((dataset_train['open'], dataset_test['open']), axis = 0)
inputs = dataset_total[len(dataset_total) - len(dataset_test) - 60:].values
inputs = inputs.reshape(-1,1)
inputs = sc.transform(inputs)
X_test = []
for i in range(60, 90):
    X_test.append(inputs[i-60:i, 0])
X_test = np.array(X_test)
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))
predicted_stock_price = regressor.predict(X_test)
predicted_stock_price = sc.inverse_transform(predicted_stock_price.reshape(-1, 1))

# Visualising the results
plt.plot(real_stock_price, color = 'red', label = 'Real IBM Stock Price')
plt.plot(predicted_stock_price, color = 'blue', label = 'Predicted IBM Stock Price')
plt.title('IBM Stock Price Prediction')
plt.xlabel('Days')
plt.ylabel('IBM Stock Price')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[Stock Prediction][1]

Comment: Hi Luis, did you solve it ?